# JSF2 (Mojarra) View Scope Managed Bean wants all members to be Serializable

Tags: view, scope, jsf-2, serializable

I am trying to convert a session scoped JSF managed bean to view scoped. However, when I try to access the xhtml page for this bean, then i get the following error:

java.io.NotSerializableException: foo.bar.SomeDaoClass

I have a member of a helper DAO that I use to delegate persistence related tasks within the bean. If I make this DAO class implement Serializable then  other UIComponent references start causing the same errors!

The main use case is that I have a link on the click of which I open a jquery lightbox pop-up showing the xhtml page which is backed by a session bean. When the user clicks the submit button on the pop-up form, I remove the session bean programatically. The problem is if the user clicks the close button of the pop-up itself, and clicks on another link pointing to another id, then the same values are shown (being session scoped)!

I would like to use the view scope to preserve values while viewing this form in a pop-up and when the user clicks the close button of the pop-up, the values may be discarded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope you've already resolved this problem, but for other people landing here, who don't want to use session scope and uses view scope as alternative, which force you to use `serializable` implementation, you can use the `transient` keyword next to the properties that you don't want to make `serializable`, that would be very helpful if you want to call a service or dao.

example:

```
@ManagedBean(name="addressTableBeanExample4")
@ViewScoped
public class ExampleBean4 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // non serialazable class
    private transient List<Customer> data = new ArrayList<Customer>();

    private Customer selected;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Referring to Balusc blog 
http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html

"In a nutshell: the @ViewScoped breaks when any UIComponent is bound to the bean using binding attribute"